# How to setup Linking table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

Updated Post
I am trying to use modelBuilder to create my linking tables for me. I was able to do a migration without errors.the Linking tables where created in the sql database.  However when i query the Jobs the Customers, ChangeOrders are still coming back Null. What do I need to query? My project does not have the Linking Table classes to reference so I am lost?

Original Post:
*I am trying to setup a linking table for my many to many relationships. Every Job can have multiple Customers  I created a "JobCustomer" to do this but the only data coming back is the Class Id's on the linking table.*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool? Hidden { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()

        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GeoArea> GeoAreas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobClass> JobClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating
   (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
        .HasMany(j => j.Customers)
        .WithMany(c => c.Jobs)
        .Map(m =>
      {
        m.ToTable("JobCustomer");
        m.MapLeftKey("JobId");
        m.MapRightKey("CustomerId");
   });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
        .HasMany(j => j.ChangeOrders)
        .WithMany(c => c.Jobs)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("JobChangeOrder");
            m.MapLeftKey("JobId");
            m.MapRightKey("ChangeOrderId");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
       .HasMany(j => j.GeoAreas)
       .WithMany(c => c.Jobs)
       .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("JobGeoArea");
           m.MapLeftKey("JobId");
           m.MapRightKey("GeoAreaId");
       });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
       .HasMany(j => j.JobTypes)
       .WithMany(c => c.Jobs)
       .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("JobJobType");
           m.MapLeftKey("JobId");
           m.MapRightKey("JobTypeId");
       });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
       .HasMany(j => j.JobClasses)
       .WithMany(c => c.Jobs)
       .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("JobJobClass");
           m.MapLeftKey("JobId");
           m.MapRightKey("JobClassId");
       });
    }

   }


  public class Job
    {

    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GeoArea> GeoAreas { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobClass> JobClasses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
}

 public List<Job> GetJobs()
    {
        List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();
        jobs = db.Jobs
            .ToList();
        return jobs;
    }
```

Comment: See if this [article](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/) helps.

Comment: so I would go through the Job class first? then the linking table?

Comment: and I would need a separate linking table for JobCustomer, JobJobType, etc..

Comment: Where is your code that actually queries the data?

Comment: k, i changed my original post with new information.